# Do I need multiple impl blocks to implement multiple methods that set a concrete type for a type parameter?

Tags: generics, rust

Consider this code that defines a trait `RefGen`, a structure `Facade` that has a property that can hold a `RefGen` and two different `new_*` methods that would pick different concrete implementations for the `RefGen`.

```
trait RefGen {
    fn gen() -> String;
}

struct FooGen;

impl RefGen for FooGen {
    fn gen() -> String {
        "foo".to_owned()
    }
}

struct BarGen;

impl RefGen for BarGen {
    fn gen() -> String {
        "bar".to_owned()
    }
}

struct Facade<R: RefGen> {
    gen: R
}

impl Facade<FooGen> {
    fn new_foogen() -> Self {
        Facade {
            gen: FooGen
        }
    }
}

impl Facade<BarGen> {
    fn new_bargen() -> Self {
        Facade {
            gen: BarGen
        }
    }
}

fn main () {}
```

It works, but it baffles me I would need two `impl` blocks for that?

Comment: could you please show how you're planning to use your Facade? I suspect you are trying to get dynamic dispatch and want some form of trait objects here.

Comment: This is probably only an intermediate step as the design is currently in it's early design stage. However I could imagine that there are three methods on the facade. `new<R: RefGen>(ref_gen: R)` would let the user decide which `RefGen` to use whereas `new_with_foo` and `new_with_bar` would set a concrete `RefGen` implementation. No dynamic dispatch here as far as I get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want named methods for each type, this is the only way. If you want to do this generically, you can use a generic impl:

```
impl<R: RefGen> Facade<R> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Facade {
            gen: R::new(),
        }
    }
}
```

This of course requires the `RefGen` trait to offer some kind of `new` function to create instances:

```
trait RefGen {
    fn gen() -> String;
    fn new() -> Self where Self: Sized;
}
```

The `where Self: Sized` bound is there so the trait is still object safe. This means that you can create a `Box<RefGen>`, but not call the `new` method.

Though now you cannot call the `gen` method on your `GenFoo` or `GenBar` object, because it's a static method. You need to add a `&self` parameter to it. In case you never want to actually create an object of type `GenFoo` or `GenBar`, because they will never have fields, you can get rid of the `gen` field and `new` constructor entirely by doing all dispatch at compile-time:

```
struct Facade<R: RefGen> {
    gen: PhantomData<R>,
}

impl<R: RefGen> Facade<R> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Facade {
            gen: PhantomData,
        }
    }
    fn gen(&self) -> String {
        R::gen()
    }
}

impl Facade<FooGen> {
    fn new_foogen() -> Self {
        Self::new()
    }
}

impl Facade<BarGen> {
    fn new_bargen() -> Self {
        Self::new()
    }
}
```